Where to initialize lock to be used for system call in xv6?
I've implemented a new system call in xv6 that tracks the number of 'read' calls since the OS boot. The system call is almost complete, but I still need to properly implement a lock to protect the increment operation. Below is the relevant section of the 'void syscall(void)' function in the 'syscall.c' file, where I added the acquire and release lock functions.
void
syscall(void)
{
  int num;
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();

  num = curproc->tf->eax;
  if (num==SYS_read){
    acquire(&count_lock);
    count++;
    release(&count_lock);
 ...

I've tried to put the
initlock(&count_lock, "counter");

in the main.c, but it gave a "implicit declaration" error and overall I'm really unsure about this solution. Could someone help me to find the correct place and file to put the initlock function?

The initlock declaration must have been seen before you use it, so you could just put that in a header file that you include in main.c - but what is main.c really in this case? I assume your tracker should be callable from any process in the system?

@TedLyngmo, yeah I got a tip about including it in main.c but I was really unsure about that. This is the main.c: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/main.c. It just feels like the wrong place to put it. And yeah, the tracker should be callable from any process.

Well, the declaration must have been seen in the translation unit in which you want to call the function, so trying to call it in any .c file without providing the declaration is most likely going to fail. What happened when you provided the declaration?

@TedLyngmo I managed to do it! I just had to add the declaration of a lock initializing function to defs.h and define it in syscall.c, calling it during system startup at the main function of main.c, and it all worked out. Thank you for your help.

Great! You're welcome!

You could/should create an answer from a cleaned up version of your last comment. You can then accept your own answer. SO encourages this. Then, the question is completed with an answer. This helps future users and also current users will spend less time on a question that already has a valid/accepted answer

Just to answer my own question - I added the declaration of a lock initializing function to "defs.h", like this:
void init_locks(void); and defined it in "syscall.c": void init_locks(void) { initlock(&countlock, "counter"); }. The function is called in the main function of "main.c", during the system startup:
int
main(void)
{
  ...
  init_locks();
  ...
}

And it all worked out.
